# jQuery traverse upwards and find

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-ui

I have a table which uses jQuery sortable to drag-drop and sort elements in a table.

When dropping an element into a "sortable-row" , I want to read the data-id from the previous "section-row" .

I've managed to achieve this for when the row is dropped in the row directly beneath a "section-row", or 2 levels below.

First level down :

```
($(ui.item[0]).closest('tr').prev('.stop-row').data('id');
```

Second level down :

```
$(ui.item[0].previousElementSibling).closest('tr').prev('tr.stop-row').data('id');
```

The problem is that a "section" can have any amount of rows added to it, so I need some kind of loop which will check if the previous element is a "section-row", if not, check on the following previous.

How do i achieve this with jQuery?

My Table:

```
<table class="table table-bordered table-responsive">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <td>Assignment</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Type</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Time</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Level</td>
        </tr>
    </thead>

    <tbody class="sortable">
        <tr class="section-row" data-id="{{ id }}">
            <td> Section-{{ id }}</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="sortable_row">
            <td>{{ assignment }}</td>
            <td>{{ type }}</td>
            <td>{{ time }}</td>
            <td>{{ level }}</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can do this:
`$(ui.item[0]).closest('tr').prevAll('.section-row:first').data('id');`

It will go to the closest `tr`, search all preceeding `tr` and stop at the first one with the class `.section-row`.

Comment: Great this what exactly what I needed.  I forgot to add that there are multiple sections in the table example, which rows can be dropped between.  This solved my problem.